# Prove that the infimum $i=\inf\{ d(a,y):y\in Y \}$ is always attained if $Y$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In [Solomon's descriptive set theory notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~solomon/notes/desc2.pdf), he asked the following exercise.

> Let $X$ be a separable, completely metrizable by a metric $d$ and contains a dense subset $D\subseteq X.$
>   Let $Y\subseteq X$ be closed and let $a\in X \setminus Y.$
>   Define 
>   $$i = \inf \{ d(a,y):y\in Y \}.$$
>   **Question:** Prove that there is an element $b\in Y$ such that $d(a,b)=i$.

My attempt: For any $n\in\mathbb{N},$ by the definition of infimum, 
$$i+\frac{1}{n} > d(a,b_n)$$
for some $b_n\in Y.$
Then the sequence $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is Cauchy. 
By completeness of $X,$ there exists $b\in X$ such that $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges to $b.$
Since $Y$ is closed, we have $b\in Y.$
Clearly $d(a,b)\leq i.$
By definition of $b\in Y,$ we have $d(a,b)\geq i.$
Hence, $d(a,b)=i.$

Is my proof correct?

EDITED: As pointed out by @5xum, my proof has a flaw. If this is the case, then how should one prove the statement above?

Comment: Maybe be more explicit for your justification of why the sequence should be Cauchy.

Comment: You have not used the fact that the space is separable in your proof, maybe that will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: The statement is not correct. One can find counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\Bbb R\cup \{a\}$ with $a\not \in \Bbb R.$ For $x,y\in \Bbb R$ let $d(x,y)=\frac {|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}.$ For $x\in \Bbb R$ let $d(a,x)=2-d(x,0).$

Let $Y=\Bbb R.$ Then $\inf \{d(a,y):y\in Y\}=1 $ but $d(a,y)=\frac {2+|y|}{1+|y|}>1$ for all $y\in Y.$

Remark. Defining $d(a,x)$ the way I did makes it easier to confirm the triangle inequality in cases involving the point $a.$ E.g. for $x,y\in \Bbb R$ we have $d(x,a)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,a)\iff$ $\iff 2-d(x,0)\leq d(x,y)+2-d(y,0)\iff$ $ d(y,0)\leq d(y,x)+d(x,0).$

Comment: I see. So the statement is always false?

Comment: It is not true for $every$ complete separable metric space. Actually separability has nothing to do with it. As mentioned in the A by Orangeskid, It is true for a metric space with the property that all bounded closed balls are compact. For example $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual (Cartesian) metric.

Comment: I see. If a metric space with the property that's all bounded closed balls are compact, then the space is essentially finite. So the statement in my post only true for finite dimensional space.

Comment: There are  several  types of topological "dimension". The  Hilbert Cube is a compact metric space of infinite dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not OK.

> Then the sequence $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is Cauchy.

First of all, you didn't prove this, and second of all, it's not even true. For example, take

$$X=\mathbb R^2\\
Y=\{(x,y)| x^2+y^2=1\}=S_1\\
a=(0,0)$$

Then, the sequence $b_n$ could be $b_n=(0,(-1)^n)$ which is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

The statement above is incorrect. It would work if say closed balls were compact ( locally compact is not enough as @Daniel Wainfleet:"s example shows)

Take $X$ the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with norm $\|f\|= \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |f(t)|$, a separable Banach space, so a separable complete metric space.

Let $$Y = \{ f \in X \mid \int_{0}^{1/2} f(t) dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t) dt = 1 \}$$

Then $d(0, Y)= 1$, but the distance is not achieved ( checking this is a good exercise).

Comment: Your counter-example is fine  but the counter-example in my A $is$ locally compact.

Comment: i@Daniel Wainfleet: So my statement is incorrect. Great example, I have to study it a bit.